# Latest version of Playhaven plugin for unity

Tags: ios, ios7, unity-game-engine, playhaven

can any one suggest the latest version of SDK PlayHaven in unity 3d... i am having problem in uploading games according to latest standards of UID.. please do help for this purpose

Comment: can anyone suggest ... or give me the link of new update sdk...

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of playhaven's unity plugin can be found here: http://help.analytics.upsight.com/api-sdk-reference/downloads/